# Does pysvn let you limit log messages in reverse order?

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

Essentially I want the same behaviour as running:

```
log = client.log(url)
oldestEntry = log[-1]
```

Except without having to download the entire log. I know setting

```
limit=1
```

lets you find the newest entry. Is there any way of limiting from the reverse order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of the `revision_start` and `revision_end` and set `limit` to 1:

```
import pysvn

url='http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/README'

epoch = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, 0)
head = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head)

client = pysvn.Client()

# Get all entries
l = client.log(url)
print len(l), l[0].revision, l[-1].revision

# Get most recent entry:
l = client.log(url, limit=1)
print len(l), l[0].revision

# Get most recent entry, again:
l = client.log(url, revision_start=head, revision_end=epoch, limit=1)
print len(l), l[0].revision

# Get least recent entry
l = client.log(url, revision_start=epoch, revision_end=head, limit=1)
print len(l), l[0].revision
```

The result is:

```
22 <Revision kind=number 1209505> <Revision kind=number 87470>
1 <Revision kind=number 1209505>
1 <Revision kind=number 1209505>
1 <Revision kind=number 87470>
```